# reshaping, merging, concat pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have a df like below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"location":["north", "south","north"], "store": ["a","b","c"], "date" : ["02112018","02152018","02182018"], "barcode1":["ok", "low","ok"], "barcode2": ["low","zero","zero"], "barcode3": ["ok","zero","low"]})
```

[image: df]

what I would like to have is like below:

[image: df_desired]

what I have done is to repeat each row, number of barcodes times with below code:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.iloc[:,:3].values,len(df.iloc[0,:3:]),axis=0))
df_1.columns = df.columns[:3]
```

and having the below output:

[image: df_1]

however I do not know how to get to df_desired.
sorry that I could not find a suitable title.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) to unpivot a dataframe, `.sort_values` by `store` gives you  the desired order of rows.

```py
pd.melt(
    df, 
    id_vars=['location', 'store', 'date'], 
    var_name='barcode', 
    value_name='control').sort_values(by=['store'])
```

---

```py
  location store      date   barcode control
0    north     a  02112018  barcode1      ok
3    north     a  02112018  barcode2     low
6    north     a  02112018  barcode3      ok
1    south     b  02152018  barcode1     low
4    south     b  02152018  barcode2    zero
7    south     b  02152018  barcode3    zero
2    north     c  02182018  barcode1      ok
5    north     c  02182018  barcode2    zero
8    north     c  02182018  barcode3     low
```